# jquery mobile Style not working

Tags: jquery, mobile

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery Mobile style not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should stumble upon this later on... 
These specific styling issues and several other similar ones occur when the programmer copied the code straight from jQuery Mobile's site and then replaced code with his IDs,values etc - because unknowingly, you also copied a series of `&nbsp;` along with the code. Those spaces went into the DOM and cause that staggering of the buttons displayed above. 
You need to either type the code yourself, manually copying the syntax from jQuery's demo page, 
OR
 delete any spaces you have between elements in your html code and then put them back in manually by hitting enter or the space bar. Those spaces aren't really spaces; they're hidden `&nbsp;`s and they come in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Lack of information, please provide more. Also, check if your js folder is in your package. Most likely you left out.